# Getting http URL using regex when there are multiple http URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract different .swf files from different sites for a project. Different sites use different source methods so I can't use `src=` or `data=` in my regex.

I'm able to match the file name with `/[\w-]+.swf/g` , but when I try to match the full path( `http(.*?).swf` ) starting with http it matches another http before the path (the first one in the code). Also I can't use `src=` or `data=` etc, it must be only the link.

Basically, is there a way to limit the match to the first http found when searching backwards?

If anyone cares to take a look then here's the code: http://pastebin.com/kT20UqqJ .
And here's a good place to test regex: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
var regex = /http:[\.\/\w-%]+\.swf/g
```

You need to escape the `.` else it will match an arbitrary character and the `/` since it is the expression delimiter.

You can see the **[working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tEWqA/)** here.

Answer (score -1):

If you have url encoded characters (like white space) you would have also a `%` in your url.

Here is an example which will work in this case: `/http:[\./\w%-]+\.swf/g`

Here is a tool where you can test the regex: http://regexpal.com/

And one where you can check it's performance: http://regexter.com/

Comment: Well, now there's no difference between both. I've added it before Christoph changed his answer. Anyway, you're welcome :-)

Comment: sure, you could have just dropped a note about adding % to my regex. Instead you just copied my regex - even with the error of the unquoted slash - very heroish:-p

Comment: You don't have to be genius to write such regex. The regular expression which you use is the one which @yodalr have provided but with added `\.` and `\/`. I see nothing so special or unique to be unable to write it by my own...Greetings for the heroish regex :D

Comment: Sure you don't have to be a genius to write such a regex, but i wonder why one would write a second answer just copying the first one when a comment would have been sufficient. There are 1000 ways to write a regex that would match the OPs need. If you just go the lazy way and copy one from an existing answer at least fix the errors in it...

Comment: There's no reason to keep argue, just read carefully my last comment and you'll answer to the question why my regex is similar to yours which is similar to the one in the question :-). Best regards...

Comment: I wasn't arguing, i was just commenting your whining:-D

Comment: Hahah ePages have really mature consultant :-))).